# Is there any open source or paid alternate to selenium for automating ext js application

Tags: extjs, automation

I am looking to automate extjs application, we all know selenium does not support extjs applications. Kindly suggest me if you have faced the same and come up with a solution for the above.

Thanks,

Comment: Sencha offers their testing tool https://www.sencha.com/products/test/ or you could use http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/ or you can still use Selenium and just write your own API functions for clicking on buttons and such - it can be done quite easily using Ext.query http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.html#method-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha offers their testing tool [sencha.com/products/test](https://www.sencha.com/products/test/) or you could use [bryntum.com/products/siesta](http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/) or you can still use Selenium and just write your own API functions for clicking on buttons and such - it can be done quite easily using [Ext.query](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.html#method-query)

I can share just a piece of our API code we used to test very specific ExtJS project where we could not use Test/Siesta. The code is written in Python.

```
def ext_component_query_return(self, query, question, target='AppManager'):
    script = 'Ext.ComponentQuery.query("{0}")[0]{1}'.format(query, question)
    return self.ext_script(script, target=target)

def ext_component_id(self, query, target='AppManager'):
    return self.ext_component_query_return(query, '.getId()', target=target)

def ext_component_isVisible(self, query, target='AppManager'):
    return self.ext_component_query_return(query, '.isVisible(true)', target=target)

def ext_component_isDisabled(self, query, target='AppManager'):
    return self.ext_component_query_return(query, '.isDisabled()', target=target)
```

Here is for example clicking on the button:

```
s_button_id = self.ext_component_id('#activation-success-card button')
s_button = self.ins.app_manager.find_element_by_id(s_button_id)
s_button.click()
```