# Functional Test With ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I'm using HP UFT for functional tests.

Because of dynamic id definition of ExtJS, I can't use UFT Recording feature.

I've tried many ways for assigning dynamic IDs to staticly.

```
I tried to change id: function() in ext-all-debug.js file.
I tried to change Components getId() function in ext-all-debug.js file.
I tried override components with afterRender method to change ids aswell.
```

Sometimes I achieved to change id's using component's properties (text, fieldLabel, overflowText, etc.), but for some components I couldn't achieve to assign ID's since the components properties seem empty.

Above, I listed my actions to assign static ID. So, I want to know your opinions about my actions and if you found them incorrect or not sufficient, could you offer me new approaches for using HP UFT recording feature with ExtJS6.

Comment: Why not just manually set the [id](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-id) config for the desired component?

Comment: I am trying to change component dom id. ExtJS creating dynamicly in front-end

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the dynamic `id` of the dom elements which represents ExtJS components. That's really bad thing and I think you would break the whole app.

The easiest way to test ExtJS app is to use already created frameworks/tools like:

[Siesta](https://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/) by Bryntum
[Sencha Test](https://www.sencha.com/products/test/#overview) by Sencha

The Siesta is free. It has some pro features which requires the license. But you can use it for free.

If you still insists on doing it your way. **You need to dynamically get the IDs of the dom elements created by ExtJS components**. Basically write your own API.
You need to execute the ExtJS JS code, which will return you the ID of the component. So you need to get the ExtJS component and call [`getId()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.Component.html#method-getId) function on it to get the dom id.

Here is the example code:

```
>Ext.ComponentQuery.query('checkbox')[0].getId()
"checkbox-1047"
```

You will definetely need: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.ComponentQuery.html#method-query
And keep in mind that the query can be pretty advanced and you can use all the configs which are set on the ExtJS elements such as name, xtype, etc

You can  find some other info in my other anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/41718879/1768843