# Selenium ui testing with its api or extjs

Tags: selenium, extjs

We have a huge web app, SPA that is written in Extjs 6. 
We test it sometimes using Selenium web driver that runs Extjs code and sometimes uses its Selenium Apis. 
Can you highlight the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: Selenuim Apis is much better as it is used world wide

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49141909/1768843