# Is it possible to capture ItemId property in extjs using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, extjs, automated-tests

I have to test an Extjs application. But the id is dynamic so there is no way to capture it. But developers have been adding another property as itemId to elements. Is there a method to capture that itemId using selenium?

Comment: Yes, you can use CSS or XPATH and use that id to identify that object

Answer (score 1):

You can execute JavaScript code on the page using Selenium to get the dynamic ID.

In this code you can use `Ext.ComponentQuery` for getting exactly the ExtJS component you want. Next using function `.getId()` you can get the dynamic ID.

```
driver.execute_script("Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myPanel').getId()")
```

You can read more in my other A to the similar problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41718879/1768843

Comment: @Joe which framework you mean ? If you want the dynamic ID's from ExtJS than you have to use ExtJS framework in your tests.

Comment: if you can please give me java code example for the above example please. I tried looking into different solutions but couldn't figure it out

Comment: Im not sure where should I create the method in order to work as expected. Please not I'm talking about E2E testing